# Why are my Cube Attributes N/A when my Dimension Attributes are not?

Tags: attributes, ssas, dimension, cubes

I cannot understand why my dimension attributes have a legitimate value, but when I view it in the Cube browser they all come up with N/A.  Any advice is appreciated.

All of the columns that have N/A's should not be N/A's:

[image]

Comment: Hard to tell without more details, and your Date column in the cube browser is collapsed.  I think that the 133million in the 2nd row is for the data you're showing in the T-SQL window (2016-03-08), implying that all values for measure Target Amount have been assigned to the N/A member.  That suggests that something's going wrong with the processing of that measure (N/A is often used as the "bin" dimension member, to which unknown or unrecognised dimension keys in the fact table get assigned).

Comment: Did you set up the relationships between the fact and dimensions on the Dimension Structure tab?